# if condition with multiple variable in golang

Tags: go

As I came from python background following go code is very confusing for me. can some one explain this?

```
if nferr, ok := err.(ops.NonFatalError); ok {
    w.NonFatalDiagnostics = w.NonFatalDiagnostics.Append(nferr.Diagnostics)
    return nil
}
```

- how the variables nferr, ok would be evaluated?
- what is the variable `ok` before opening curly brace?
- statement `return nil`, does it return from the function, the code is in?

Comment: See the following in the tour: [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), [if with a short statement](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6)

Answer (score 1):

This is called the "comma ok" idiom in Go which is essentially the same with:

```
nferr, ok := err.(ops.NonFatalError)
if ok {
    w.NonFatalDiagnostics = w.NonFatalDiagnostics.Append(nferr.Diagnostics)
    return nil
}
```

The only difference is the scope of `nferr` and `ok` which is within the `if` block.

> how the variables nferr, ok would be evaluated?

If `err` is of type `ops.NonFatalError`, `nferr` will the concrete type of `ops.NonFatalError`, otherwise, `ok` will be false and `nferr` will be the zero value of `ops.NonFatalError`.

> what is the variable ok before opening curly brace?

Look at the code above, it is essentially the same.

> statement return nil, does it return from the function, the code is in?

Yes.

**Edit**

From @ThunderCat's comment which I highly suggest you go through, the Go tour explains a lot of syntax:

[Type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)

[If with a short statement](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6)